# Connect containers apache2, jboss and mongo

Tags: docker

I have 3 containers: apache2,jboss and container mongo, i configure each container and problem now how can i do to connect all containers in this order: container apache2 communicate with container jboss and container jboss communicate with container mongo

need your help please

Comment: There are weeks of learning to fill out a proper answer ... here is a tutorial where it outlines the notion of Replication Controllers and Services which are essential for any realistic multi container app  https://medium.com/google-cloud/running-a-mean-stack-on-google-cloud-platform-with-kubernetes-149ca81c2b5d#.v6cy7ssi2